# dfs in python not working please guide me about errors

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def dfs(graph, start, visited=None):

    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    if start in visited:
        return
    visited.add(start)
    for a in graph[start]:
        if a not in visited:
            dfs(graph, a, visited)
    return visited
graph={'A':['B'],'B':['C']}

b=dfs(graph,'A')

print(b)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    dfs(graph,'A')
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 7, in dfs
    dfs(graph,start,visited)
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 7, in dfs
    dfs(graph,start,visited)
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 7, in dfs
    dfs(graph,start,visited)

Comment: I presume the code is from http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/  the examples in that presume you don't have a directedgraph and all the children are nodes themselves

Answer (score 0):

`graph[start]` will raise [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) if `start` is not in the dictionary. You can replace it with [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to return default value (empty sequence):

```
def dfs(graph, start, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    if start in visited:
        return
    visited.add(start)
    for a in graph.get(start, []):  # <---
        if a not in visited:
            dfs(graph, a, visited)
    return visited
```